# Django Formset not being processed properly

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I'm making a web application for registering teams for different events at an inter-school competition.

Registration for the event will take place via a webpage consisting of a Django formset.

My problem is that, although all the elements of the formset show up on the webpage, when I click the "Submit" button on it, the relevant data is not processed at all.

Also, as given in `BaseEventTeamFormset()` in `forms.py`, there should be a 3rd text field called `mem3` in the form, when the `event.label` is Quiz. However, this 3rd field fails to show up on the webpage.

I have included the necessary files here. Please help me rectify this error.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class School(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField('Name of school', max_length=30)
    currCap = models.IntegerField('Current Capital')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):

    EVENTS = (
    ('Quiz', 'Quizzing'),
    ('Design', 'Design'),
    ('Robot', 'Robotics'),
    ('Prog', 'Programming'),
    ('Photo', 'Photography'),
#   ('SurEven', 'Surprise Event'),
)

    memDict = {
    'Quiz': 3,
    'Design': 2,
    'Robot': 2,
    'Prog': 2,
    'Photo': 1,
#   'SurEven': 2,   
}

    name = models.CharField('Name of event', max_length = 20, choices = EVENTS)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name.verbose_name


class EventTeam(models.Model):

    school = models.ForeignKey('School')
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')

    def __unicode__(self):
        str = self.event + ': ' + self.school.name
        return str


class Member(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name of member', max_length = 20)
    events = models.ManyToManyField('EventTeam')

    def __unicode(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class EventTeamForm(forms.Form):

    event = forms.BooleanField()
    mem1 = forms.CharField(label="Member 1", max_length = 20)
    mem2 = forms.CharField(label="Member 2", max_length = 20, required = False)

    if event.label == 'Quizzing':
        mem3 = forms.CharField(label="Member 3", max_length = 20, required = False)

class BaseEventTeamFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseEventTeamFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for i in range(0, len(Event.EVENTS)):
        self[i].fields['event'].label = Event.EVENTS[i][1]


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'descr', 'upForAcq'
    )
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url = '/xdashboard/login/')
def register(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    currSchool = School.objects.get(user = request.user)
    eventTuple = Event.EVENTS
    noOfEvents = len(eventTuple)
    EventTeamFormSet = formset_factory(EventTeamForm, extra = noOfEvents - 1, formset=BaseEventTeamFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = EventTeamFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():  
            i = 0
            for form in formset:
                participating = form.cleaned_data['event']

                if participating == True:

                    event = Event.objects.get(pk = i+1)

                    mem1 = form.cleaned_data['mem1']
                    mem1 = Member(name = mem1)
                    mem1.save()
                    mem2 = form.cleaned_data['mem2']
                    mem2 = Member(name = mem2)
                    mem2.save()

                    if event == "Quiz":
                        mem3 = form.cleaned_data['mem3']
                        mem3 = Member(name = mem3)
                        mem3.save()

                    # creating database queries, many mistakes!

                    team = EventTeam(school = currSchool, event = event)
                    team.save()
                    mem1.events.add(team) # adding the members to the team
                    mem2.events.add(team)
                    try:
                        mem3.events.add(team)
                    except NameError:
                        pass

                    i += 1

    else:
        formset = EventTeamFormSet()

    context_dict = {
    'formset': formset,
    }

    return render_to_response('xdashboard/register.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: Please fix the whitespace of your code. Is the formset definitely valid? Have you tried printing `formset.errors` when formset.is_valid() is `False`?

Comment: Some of the whitespace has been formatted incorrectly here, but otherwise it's alright on my machine. I'll just try printing `formset.errors`.

Comment: You are not using `BaseEventTeamFormSet` at all? `if event.label == 'Quizzing': ...` in forms.py should be in `__init__()` method.

Comment: It's important that the whitespace is the same as your code. It's looking more sensible now. Before I couldn't tell which `if` statement the `else` statement went with.

Comment: My apologies, Alasdair. 

Yeah, I am using it, as given in `EventTeamFormSet = formset_factory(EventTeamForm, extra = noOfEvents - 1, formset=BaseEventTeamFormSet)` in `views.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your for loop lacks proper indentation in your forms.py and needs to be inside the `__init__()` method. It would help to look at your template code. My best guess is that your `formset.is_valid()` method returns false and none of your on submission data processing takes place on the POST.

For debugging sake use `{{ field.errors }}` and `{{ forms.non_field_errors }}` in your template.

Comment: On your advice, I looked through my template code and found that I had forgot to close a <div> tag. Grr... Thank you so much.